# My wife wants to peg me, is this Halal?

Tags: sex, muslim-practices

The other day my wife asked if she can peg me because it is something she has wanted to do for a long time.

My question is: is this haram?

Comment: It is alright between couples as long as both agree

Answer (score 0):

my friend, in relation to your question, if you do not want to do this, then yes, your wife has done something haram. Sexual intercourse and what happens in that case must be agreed upon by both parties, and this is my answer based on the opinion of Islamic religious scholars.

Answer (score 0):

No way.
In Islam, sanctity and proper behavior within the bounds of marriage are clearly defined and what you are saying deviates from these rules.

The idea of pegging is explicitly forbidden because it comes under sodomy which is a major sin. According to Islam, the act itself is considered an attack on the respect and sanity that sexual relations are supposed to embody in a marriage.

In Islam, sexual intercourse is considered not only a means of procreation, but also a means of cultivating love, kindness and closeness between husband and wife.

Actions that deviate from the conventional and ethical system established by the Shari'ah are considered haram.

Remember that the instructions given in Islam regarding marital relations and sexual behavior are to ensure that Muslim activities  are in accordance with the divine will as communicated through  Quran and  Hadith.

It is important to adhere to these rules to preserve the virtue and sanctity of the marital relationship as intended by Islam. If you are looking  to improve intimacy and cooperation in your marriage, focus on strategies and approaches that align with Islamic teachings, always prioritizing your happiness and comfort.